# SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I would appreciate some help on this exception.

I did some research on this error but I could not find a solution. I use JPA with hibernate and get this error when executing a query.

Obviously, there's something that I don't understand about java LocalDate and oracle Date. :(

This is the object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1731972128723930612L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OTHER_ID", nullable = false)
    private OtherObject otherObject;

    @Column(name = "MY_DATE", columnDefinition="DATE", nullable = false)
   // @Convert(converter = LocalDateSQLDateConverter.class)
   // @Convert(converter = LocalDateConverter.class)
    private LocalDate date;
```

As you can see, I tried to use converters which convert LocalDate to java.util.Date or java.sql.Date and viceversa - both did unfortunately not help.

This is the query:

```
public class MyDao extends BaseDao {

    public void save(MyObject object) {
        entityManager.persist(object);
    }

    public MyObject findByDate(LocalDate date) {
        TypedQuery<MyObject> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT w from MyObject w"
                + " where w.date = :date", MyOBject.class)
                .setParameter("date", date);
        return query.getResultList().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
```

This is the exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:
>   expected DATE got BINARY
>
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
>     oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1493)
>     org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
>     org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2090)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1866)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:905)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:347)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2578)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2564)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2394)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2389)
>     org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
>     org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
>     org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:198)
>     org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1230)
>     org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
>     org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268)
>     my.company.path.MyDao.findByDate(MyDaoDao.java:21)

Thanks a lot in advance for any hints!

Comment: What version is your Oracle JDBC driver? try a fresher one!

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to change it as it is given in the jboss docker image.

Comment: I found out that I did not use the newest JPA version & changed it. Unfortunately, the problem remained. I exchanged LocalDate & LocalDateTime in my application with java.util.Date, and that works. But I would really prefer to use LocalDate & LocalDateTime.

Comment: Try something like this: https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Comment: I found that, too, and tried it, unfortunately, no success.

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems like counter intuitive, you should pass a string representation, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx where date_of_birth = '1990-08-21';
```

where `date_of_birth` is of type `DATE` (`MySQL`, not `Oracle`, but shouldn't matter) and mapped to `LocalDate` in `Spring`/`Hibernate`

Comment: In Oracle you might want to use `TO_CHAR()`/`TO_DATE()` as it does not coexists well with standards...

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 4 came out before java.time.LocalDate was added and it does not understand it.  It therefore sends the data as binary to Oracle.

The best fix is to upgrade to Hibernate 5.

Comment: Mmh, actually I am using hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar.

Comment: Your answer led me to find out that I didn't use JPA 2.2 which in theory supports LocalDate & LocalDateTime. Unfortunately, the problem was not solved by this change.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that our docker image uses JBoss 6.4, which - according to https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673 - uses Hibernate **JPA 2.0**.

So, this can't work. We need **JPA 2.2** to support LocalDate & LocalDateTime.

I changed all occurrences of LocalDate and LocalDateTime in the DAOs with Date, while the rest of my app continues to use LocalDate and LocalDateTime - with the help of a little converter:

```
public class LocalDateConverter {

    public static Date convertToDate(LocalDate date) {
        return date != null ? Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()) : null;
    }

    public static LocalDate convertToLocalDate(Date date) {
        return date != null ? LocalDate.from(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())) : null;
    }

    public static Date convertToDate(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        return dateTime != null ? Date.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()) : null;
    }
}
```

Theoretically, there is one method missing which converts Date to LocalDateTime, but in my case I don't need it because I use LocalDateTime only for creationDates which are never read.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in the mapping of the output but the mapping of the parameter.

While hibernate manage beans, it knows it must convert from LocalDate to Date.

I don't know why but entityManager doesn't do the same for parameters input. I assume entityManager has a shorter list of known classes with converters and others are converted using toString().

You have to convert your input parameter to Date:

> ```
> TypedQuery<MyObject> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT w from MyObject w"
>             + " where w.date = :date", MyOBject.class)
>             .setParameter("date",Date.from(date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
> ```

If you use Spring, you may also org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query

> ```
>  @Query("SELECT w from MyObject w where w.date = :date")
>  public MyObject findByDate(LocalDate date);
> ```
>
> It will automatically convert your input parameter.